# Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell-extensions

I tryed install gnome extesions. But i always recive the message 'Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.'.

I installed the gnome-shell-extensions and chrome-gnome-shell but no working.

I restart the computer and tryed a in other browser. The message continue.

I am use Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.01 LTS.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Budgie isn't GNOME Shell, so the error is correct. To install GNOME Shell extensions you need to be running GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your terminal:

gnome-shell --replace

Answer (score -1):

Try installing it with:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29336233)

Comment: @Wojtek_B: This is an answer. It may not be a correct answer—I'm can't say—but that would be a reason to downvote it, not to delete it. The _Low Quality Posts_ queue is for answers that consist only of links, are duplicates, or don't attempt to answer the question at all (e.g., by asking a follow-up question, saying "thank you", or noting that they have the same problem). Short answers, code-only answers, and even incorrect answers should all be maintained—though, again, you're free to downvote them if you feel they aren't useful.

Comment: Well I had the exact same problem as the OP and this answer solved it for me